# What's the point of the old people's interviews in When Harry Met Sally

Tags: analysis, film-techniques, when-harry-met-sally

Why did *When Harry Met Sally ... (1989)* occasionally show interviews of random old couples retelling their love stories? Is there a name for this technique? I noticed that there was a time jump after each insert and towards the end

> we saw the interview with Harry and Sally after they had declared their love for one another.

Initially, I was intrigued by these random interviews but after a few of them, I got impatient and slightly annoyed because I failed to understand their point. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The movie is a love story about 2 people who didn't love each other at first, but eventually grew to love each other.  The point of the movie was based on the concept of; "Can a man and a woman ever really be **just friends**".  However, at its heart it's a romance movie that was written following director Rob Reiner's divorce.

The interviews were actually conducted between the writer and some of the people who worked for the production company, discussing how they met their significant other.  While actors were used for those scenes, the dialogue was based on those interviews.

You should probably check out [the Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_Harry_Met_Sally...) that exists as it adds a lot of context to the movie.